# what is the css fix for desktop pc, that css fix should not disturb media device css code styles,

Tags: css

what is the css fix for desktop PC, that css fix should not disturb media device css code styles,

for mobile this css fix will work out @media handheld,

is there any css fix for PC.

Comment: @media handheld,this fix will work only media device, like that i need for desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen
```

This will allow you to make rules for only computers with normal sized screens. There is a full list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@media;